# Insert a column to the right of the active cell and autofilling formulas from previous column

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to this forum and also VBA, so if this needs clarification, just let me know and I apologize in advance!

I am trying to use VBA to insert a new column to the right of the active cell and format the new column with all formulas from the left adjacent column.  I can do this by using the copy and paste functions, but Excel is very slow when running the code.

```
Sub MyInsertColumn()

Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatRightOrAbove
Cells(6, ActiveCell.Column -1).Copy
Cells(6, ActiveCell.Column).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Cells(7, ActiveCell.Column -1).Copy
Cells(7, ActiveCell.Column).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Cells(8, ActiveCell.Column -1).Copy
Cells(8, ActiveCell.Column).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This code also will not format the new desired column unless I run the code twice, and another column has been inserted.

I want to be able to use the code for a range of rows. For example from 6 to 24.

Comment: Could you clarify, what problem you're looking to solve? Is it that you want to use the above code for a range of rows? Or that you want a faster function to do the work you described?

Comment: screenshots of the input and expected output would be helpful

Comment: I don't think this code that I have will satisfy what I am trying to do.  I know that it can, but it is very slow just using copy and paste for each individual cell.  So yes, I want a faster function.  I need to copy the formulas for rows 6 through 24, 29 through 47, and 52 through 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question completely but it seems like this is the code you require

```
Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range(Cells(6, Selection.Column), Cells(24, Selection.Column)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I made it a simple to understand. I recommend pressing F8 and running the code line by line to understand how it works

Comment: Okay this is working.  But now I can't figure out how to make this work for multiple ranges of rows.  There are 3 different tables, so I'll need to autofill the formulas from rows 6 through 24, 29 through 47, and 52 through 70.

Comment: simply copy paste the 3, 4th and 5th line of code by changing 6 and 24 to 29 and 47 respectively, same for 52 to 70

Comment: I've tried that, but it only seems to be pasting the formulas for rows 6 through 24.  Would creating a new sub for each subsequent range of rows help?

Comment: The selection changes when you paste so you will need to add
selection.offset(0,-1).select

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience!! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct [XlInsertFormatOrigin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlinsertformatorigin-enumeration-excel) enumeration and FillRight.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyInsertColumn()

    With Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)
        .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        .Offset(0, -1).Cells(6, 1).Resize(3, 1).FillRight
    End With

End Sub
```

This assumes that you are somewhere on the column that you want to copy the formulas from.

Comment: This does just what I need it to do!  Thank you!  I am not familiar with what the resize is for.  And if I need it for rows 6 through 24 to fill right, would I need to input a range function somewhere?

Comment: Well that's different from your question but rows 6 through 24 is 19 rows so change it to .Resize(19, 1). IOW, take a single cell and resize it to 19 rows by 1 column then fill right.